# How can we limit the tabs in Xamarin forms Shell tabBar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a app with Flyout menu and tabbar is removed in Xamarin Forms.
Now we wants tabbar also. we need 3 tabs and rest all the option in last MENU tab.
Is there any way to limit the tabs in Tab bar in Shell tabbar?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LULxU.jpg)

Comment: This is caused by system design.  When there are more than five tabs on a TabBar, a More tab will appear, which can be used to access the additional tabs.

Comment: @wendy thank you. But what we want is only 3 tabs in bottom and a menu options. How can we achieve this ?

Comment: I'm afraid this couldn't be easily changed. It is by design. You need to completely override its architecture if you don't like this default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the Shell template, the `BottomNavigationView` provide a `MaxItemCount` to set the count of tabs to five.

```
 public virtual int MaxItemCount { get; }
```

This count only can get. We could not set the value for this via custom renderer or other ways.

If you really wat to do this, you need to create your own `BottomNavigationView`. This couldn't be easily changed.